# how to override minicart phtml file using custom module

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.9

I am trying to override minicart phtml file,
used this code in config.xml->

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <rakesh_webr module="Webr">
            <file>webr.xml</file>
        </rakesh_webr>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

and this in my layout config file (webr.xml)->

```
<layout>
     <sales_order_view>
       <reference name="sales.order.view">
          <action method="setTemplate">
             <template>webr/sales/order/view.phtml</template>
          </action>
       </reference>`enter code here`
    </sales_order_view>
    <sales_order_print>
       <reference name="sales.order.print">
          <action method="setTemplate">
             <template>webr/sales/order/print.phtml</template>
          </action>
       </reference>
   </sales_order_print>
</layout>
```

and i have put the templates in right  folder but nothing is working

Comment: you mean top mini cart in header?

Comment: yeah you can call that ajaxcart too (supported only in magento 1.9)

Comment: (1) This XML is invalid unless this is just a typo: `enter code here`? (2) Those don’t look like the blocks you need to update the templates on. (3) You probably need to make your update in the `<default>` handle for header, rather than `<sales_order_view>` and `<sales_order_print>`.

Comment: sorry what i meant was that i followed these things,resolved it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

In your layout add the xml file.

Add this inside the magento `root\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\yourcompany.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="checkout/cart_minicart" name="minicart_head" template="checkout/cart/minicart.phtml" before="-">
                <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart_content" template="checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>yourcompany/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>yourcompany/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Then create the file in magento `root\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\yourcompany\checkout\cart\minicart\default.phtml`

```
//Write your magic code here
```